# How to properly link an installed library to the CMake in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, dll

I have a CMake project that uses `mosquittopp`. It is properly running on Linux without needing any additional configurations (i.e. `#include <mosquittopp.h>` works without `target_include_directories`; and libraries are linked without `find_library`)

However, when I try the same on Windows, I am constantly having `undefined reference` problems. Here is the minimal reproducible example:

1. Install `mosquitto` to the system; Here are some files from `C:/Program Files/mosquitto`:

```
├── libcrypto.dll
├── libssl.dll
├── mosquitto.dll
├── mosquitto.exe
├── mosquittopp.dll
├── devel
│   ├── mosquitto.h
│   ├── mosquitto.lib
│   ├── mosquittopp.h
│   └── mosquittopp.lib
```

2. Write and save the following to `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mosquittopp.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world";

    mosqpp::lib_init();

    return 0;
}
```

3. Create the following `CMakeLists.txt` file:

111

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15) 
project(sandbox LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(MainFile main.cpp)

target_include_directories(MainFile PUBLIC "C:/Program Files/mosquitto/devel")
target_link_libraries(MainFile "C:/Program Files/mosquitto/devel/mosquittopp.lib")


set_property(TARGET MainFile PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
set_property(TARGET MainFile PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED On)
set_property(TARGET MainFile PROPERTY CXX_EXTENSIONS Off)
```

I tried to use different combinations of `find_library()`, absolute paths, adding and removing `dll` files, adding all `lib` files but to no avail.

EDIT: The error message in this example is:

```
[build] C:/Users/myuser/OneDrive/Desktop/test/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN6mosqpp8lib_initEv'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\MainFile.dir\build.make:101: MainFile.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/MainFile.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2
```

this is a minimal reproducible example, but the similar errors arise in the full project as well.

Comment: There are two `.lib` files. Perhaps you need to link with *both*?

Comment: I've quickly checked their github and there are plenty of dependencies. So unless you paste out the errors (i.e. `undefined references`) - we won't have enough information to know why this is failing.

Comment: @MilanŠ. I added the error message in the edit. Thanks

Comment: Please run a verbose build (run `make VERBOSE=1`), so `make` outputs all the commands it uses to build the application. Then you can see exactly the libraries it uses to link with.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that won't be needed. The issue is elsewhere (it's mentioned in my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know where the issue is now after looking at the error message and checking out mosquitopp.

My current guess is that you've downloaded pre-compiled binaries from [their download page.](https://mosquitto.org/download/)

These binaries were built using `MSVC (2019)` however you are using `mingw32` to build your project. This is apparent from the line here:

```
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\MainFile.dir\build.make:101: MainFile.exe] Error 1
```

You cannot use different compilers, the binaries will always most likely be different. So you have two options now to solve this:

- Build your own mosquittopp library using mingw32
- Build your application using MSVC 2019